Rename the tag in the XML file
Please tell me how you can rename replace a tag using Notepad++:
<offer id="124439" name="Alchimia Olive 7,5x30">

Replace by
<offer>Alchimia Olive 7,5x30</offer> <id>124439</id>

The XML file is large if manually, I would like to do with a little blood

Are id and name always in same order?

Welcome prokesha! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!


Ctrl+H
Find what: <offer id="(\d+)" name="([^"]+)">
Replace with: <offer>$2</offer> <id>$1</id>
TICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
SELECT Regular expression
UNTICK . matches newline
Replace all

Explanation:
<offer id="     # literally
(\d+)           # group 1, 1 or more digits
" name="        # literally
([^"]+)         # group 2, 1 or more any character that is not a quote
">              # literally

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):


If id and name can be present in any order, use:

Find what: <offer(?=.*id="(?<id>\d+)")(?=.*name="(?<name>[^"]+)").+?>
Replace with: <offer>$+{name}</offer> <id>$+{id}</id>


Thanks, it helped!

@prokesha: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, How to accept an answer
